# How to post whole data to backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I am new to web development(Front end) and I have created a form and when I hit submit I want to post the values into the controller "/data" in the backend as a JSON.

So this my code to post the data

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn btn-warning", function(e) {
  var params = {
    username: $(".input-group[name=names]").val(),
    email: $(".input-group[name=email]").val(),
    nicknames: $(".input-group[name=names]").val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: back + "/data",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Please enter the correct credentials: " + errorThrown);

    }
  });
});
```

My working 
[pen](http://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/OmBQdw)

Comment: What you have done should work, do you have a problem with it? I would however strongly suggest that you remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice, and the browser will be giving you warnings in the console telling you not to use it

Comment: And what's your question / issue?

Comment: If you want to pass your data as JSON, then don't convert it to a string. Send `data : params`. I don't know why everybody stringifies their JSON data, and at this point I'm too afraid to ask.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  If I do a console log I am unable to see anything?

Comment: Can anyone able to log all the data in the console to check?

Comment: @Ricky where have you put the `console.log()`? It should be in the `success` handler, like this: `console.log(data);` If that doesn't show anything, is the alert in the `error` handler being shown? Also, check the network tab of the console to see what's going on with the request

Comment: Also, I just noticed your `".btn btn-warning"` selector looks wrong. Try `".btn.btn-warning"`